# ubuntu how to use Intel integrating graphic card to rendering desktop, NV card to do calculate

Tags: ubuntu, intel, nvidia

I have a machine, which have two graph card, one integrate in the intel cpu and another plug in pci slot(NV). The OS is ubuntu 16.04.2, I want to use the integrating one for desktop rendering and the NV for MXNet calculate. By default, the OS choose the NV car to use, after I switch to use the integrating one in "NVIDIA X Server settings", the nvidia-smi dosen't working.

```
nvidia-smi

sudo nvidia-smi 
NVIDIA-SMI couldn't find libnvidia-ml.so library in your system.
Please make sure that the NVIDIA Display Driver is properly installed 
and present in your system.  
Please also try adding directory that contains libnvidia-ml.so to your 
system PATH.
```

and google around add a LD_PRELOAD.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/nvidia-367/libnvidia-ml.so nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

so, any one have experience on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have setup what i want, and posted the steps on github.
if you have the same issue, please check https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/issues/5385

Hope, it will help.